# Fade-in images on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this:

```
<div id="container" class="loading">
<header id="gallery-header">
    <div id="top-bar-gallery">
        <a href="../index.html">HOME</a>
    </div>
</header>
<div id="gallery-main" role="main" >
    <div id="image" class="loading">
    <a><img src="roma/roma2.jpg" alt"" /></a>
        <a><img src="../css/images/gallery-loaderx.gif" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
</div> <!--! end of #container -->
```

but gallery loader doesn't show? I can't seem to work it out.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Nothing in the code you show would cause a fade-in. What plugin are you using? How are you initializing it?

Comment: You need to post your jQuery/JavaScript.

Comment: some plugins are style.css, modernizr-1.7.min.js, jquery.js, jquery-ui.min.js, nexHelpers.js, jquery.nexGallery.js, jquery.scrollTo-min.js

Comment: yes, but can you show the javascript or jquery that is on this page that calls the animation?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any JS? or do you need some solution to fade-in images after the page loads?
if you only need the images/content to fadeIn, you would need to include Jquery and then do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //hides the images
    $("#images").hide();

    // starts a time counter so you can fade the images later on (when page loads)
    var imageFader= setTimeout(function(){  
         $("#images").fadeIn();

    },2000); // 2 seconds (adjust if needed);


});
```

You can also apply this method to trigger/activate functions

Hope this helps.

Comment: Im so lost, somebody I can PM/mail my site to so I can show my little problem live?